# Tridion core service difference between save create and checkIn methods

Tags: 2011, core-service

I saw that there are different method to create a component using core service and a client like **SessionAwareCoreServiceClient**.

what is the main difference between **.Save**() and **.Create**() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Create` is used to create new items only. It will perform `Save` + `CheckIn`.

`Save` can be used to create new, or save existing items. It will not check-out or check item in

`Update` will execute `CheckOut` + `Save` + `CheckIn`

Answer (score 4):

If you do a create, you're actually creating a brand new item.   If you do a save, you're either saving an existing item, or saving the new item that you've created.

Short answer, but I hope it clears up the confusion.

Comment: So save is working with new components or updated components.
So everytime we have to create or update a component we have to use the Save() at the end ?